# Looping CharAt to convert a String to ASCII

Tags: java, loops

Hi guys i made this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//Creates a class

public class codeString {

    public static void main(String[] arg) { //creates scanne/giving name
        Scanner ImBack = new Scanner(System.in);

        //print out "enter any String" and asks to put in data
        System.out.print("Enter any String :");
        String Word = ImBack.nextLine();

        int ascii = (int) Word.charAt(0);
        System.out.println(ascii);
        System.out.println((char) Word.charAt(0));
    }
}
```

But when i run it it converts only 1 letter, I know that i have to make a loop..
so then i went on google and made this

```
for (Word.charAt(0); Word = int; Word = Word) {
    System.out.println("" + Word);
}
```

printing lots of errors, one of them was asking for toString, but it worked with out the toString for the one letter, so i know i did loop wrong 100%, could anyone help? and will i need a

```
    length
```

in there?

Comment: Maybe you should read up on loops in Oracle's online Java tutorial.

Comment: Always include the errors you're getting and begin by trying to research the proper usage of constructs like `for` loops before asking questions.

Comment: The loop you need is one of the simplest. If it's complicated you have done something wrong.

Comment: ... or look at any example of a loop which increments a counter like `i` it would be closer to what you need.

Comment: just make a loop for the length of String , then its counter will show the char that you selected , if you can't write this program yourself start reading from the basic things

Comment: The correct term for the value returned by `charAt` is "UTF-16 code unit," or generically (but imprecisely) "character code." ASCII is a different character set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need something like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < Word.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println(Word.charAt(i));
}
```

1. `Word.length()` return to you the length of your word or text
2. `Word.charAt(i)` to get character by character

You can learn also the Oracle tutorials about [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and [do...while Loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

Comment: Thanks dude it helped alot more than the Content for loops online!

Comment: @OleV.V. Hi Ole. Upvote comes only with 15+ rep http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges but accept would be nice....

Comment: @OleV.V. He he now he can do it :)